# $_SESSION PHP is not recognized on the same server in different URL

Tags: php, session

I have a check_session.php file that checks if the user session was started after login, which happens is as follows:

There are two URL's:

https://www.website.com/control/user/

And inside it has a link that leads to another URL:

https://www.website.com/b2b/user/

At the beginning of each page you even have the code:

```
<?php
if( !session_id() ) {
    session_start();
}
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.website.com');
?>
```

The file check_session.php is the same for both environments, however when opening the link in a target="_blank", the other URL passes through the file verify.php and $_SESSION['user'] is not recognized and forwards the user out of the environment, but the source tab does not lose the session:

```
<?php
if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    echo "<script>window.alert('Unauthorized access [SECTION OFF]!');</script>";
    echo "<script>parent.location.href='home/';</script>";
    exit();
}
?>
```

Taking into account that the destination URL call is done both via tag and in Jquery .ajax();

great regardz, thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you run session_start() prior to session_id()?

Comment: @Darius if you run `session_start` before `session_id`, it'll set it rendering the check useless

Comment: Ahh, learned a new thing, haven't used sessions like that in ages. Anyway @Eliseu B. check if the url's match. Does the originating url and final url have http or https? does it have www. or no www? they should match up.

Comment: @Darius The logic is to check if session_id () was not started previously, so the session is created. Is it wrong?

Comment: @Darius , both use's SSL and www. in URL

Comment: I actually use //www.website.com when passing the URL on the call.

Comment: If you are using sessions just put `session_start()` at the top of your files and be done with it. There is no need to check if a session is already started.

Comment: @JohnConde I made the change as suggested, but no WARNING or NOTICE or other type of notification is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen in 2 cases:
First is different domain names. You said, that they are same.

Then most likely you didn't init session in verify.php

Header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` using, when you need to load data from another site. You don't need that header on same domain. And you don't need to check `session_id` before start session.

So first piece of code may look like this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

In the second piece of code, if `$_SESSION['user']` were not set, then there is no sense to `unset($_SESSION['user']);`.

If you destroy session, no need to `session_regenerate_id(true);`.

If you recreate session only because of `$_SESSION['user']` and this code is all in this file,

then second piece of code may look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    echo "<script>window.alert('Unauthorized access [SECTION OFF]!');</script>";
    echo "<script>parent.location.href='home/';</script>";
}
```

If you recreate session for another reason, then second piece may look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    echo "<script>window.alert('Unauthorized access [SECTION OFF]!');</script>";
    echo "<script>parent.location.href='home/';</script>";
}
```